# How to use common engine in Ktor

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Hey I am trying to implement KMM in my existing Android and iOS project. I following this [kmm-config](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html#mpp-config). I want to implement interceptor and authentication. In doc example both Android and iOS ktor engine is separated in androidMain and iosMain respectively. So I want to write interceptor in both platform like separate or just use in commonMain. Is there is a way to use common engine in both platform? Thanks

Comment: There is no common engine for kmm, as @Praveen mention, but if you write your code in common and you have different engines as dependencies and you will not define it, the HttpClient will define engine by platform dependency.

Answer (score 1):

`HTTP Engines` are platform-dependent, so you have to use different engines for each platform, which you can define in each platform's `shared` package.

Create a variable with `expect` keyword, inside `commonMain`

```
expect val httpEngine: HttpEngine
```

Provide an `actual` declaration inside each platform `Main` package

Android

```
actual val httpEngine = Android.create {
    //configure intercepter here
}
```

IOS

```
acutal val httpEngine = Ios.create {
    //configure intercepter here
}
```

You can use this `httpEngine` inside `commonMain` package to create an `HttpClient` and configure authentication

```
fun createHttpClient(httpEngine: HttpClientEngine) =
    HttpClient(httpEngine) {
        install(Auth) {
            //configure authentication
        }
    }
```

You can read more about `ktor authentication` [here](https://ktor.io/docs/auth.html)

Comment: Hey @Praveen Can I get the sample project ?

Comment: https://github.com/joreilly/PeopleInSpace  and https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit are good projects to start with.